# Openssl invalid_purpose

Tags: openssl

What certificate fields are looked when Openssl generates invalid_purpose?

I am generating the certificates using OpenSSL.

First I generate a master certificate, followed by  client certificate. Now when I am trying to connect with server, it generates Invalid_Purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an extension `keyUsage` which specifies what can be done with the certificate. Note that some programs are not using this field.

From X509 documentation:

```
X509_V_ERR_INVALID_PURPOSE: unsupported certificate purpose
    the supplied certificate cannot be used for the specified purpose.
```

Man page [x509v3_config(5)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html) lists possible values for the parameter and also for another called `extendedKeyUsage`:

```
Key Usage.
    Key usage is a multi valued extension consisting of a list of names of
    the permitted key usages.

    The supporte names are: digitalSignature, nonRepudiation,
    keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement, keyCertSign, cRLSign,
    encipherOnly and decipherOnly.

    Examples:
     keyUsage=digitalSignature, nonRepudiation
     keyUsage=critical, keyCertSign 

Extended Key Usage.
    This extensions consists of a list of usages indicating purposes for
    which the certificate public key can be used for,

    These can either be object short names of the dotted numerical form of
    OIDs.  While any OID can be used only certain values make sense. In
    particular the following PKIX, NS and MS values are meaningful:

     Value                  Meaning
     -----                  -------
     serverAuth             SSL/TLS Web Server Authentication.
     clientAuth             SSL/TLS Web Client Authentication.
     codeSigning            Code signing.
     emailProtection        E-mail Protection (S/MIME).
     timeStamping           Trusted Timestamping
     msCodeInd              Microsoft Individual Code Signing (authenticode)
     msCodeCom              Microsoft Commercial Code Signing (authenticode)
     msCTLSign              Microsoft Trust List Signing
     msSGC                  Microsoft Server Gated Crypto
     msEFS                  Microsoft Encrypted File System
     nsSGC                  Netscape Server Gated Crypto

    Examples:
     extendedKeyUsage=critical,codeSigning,1.2.3.4
     extendedKeyUsage=nsSGC,msSGC
```

Comment: The link to the X.509 config man page is broken. The updated link is: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html. Just in case that link will be broken again, enter OpenSSL site, https://www.openssl.org/, and navigate in the following way: docs >> manual pages >> master >> file formats

Answer (score 2):

At the nuts and bolts level, the openssl.cnf values you used probably had some other kind of usage, like email. This is why they were invalid for the server connection you were trying to make.

Check your openssl.cnf contents, and look at the samples delivered in the OpenSSL sources for something likely to work with a stock TLS web server connecting to a conventional web browser.